# Can somebody tell what is maximum no of ipa builds which can exist in Crashlytics Beta. Also for how many days can a build exist in Beta?

Tags: ios, crashlytics-beta

I tried searching but couldn't find anything.
The problem is I am using CircleCI and deploying an ipa each day in Crashlytics. But if there a limit on the no of ipas that can exist in the Beta-Crashlytics, then there is no point in building an ipa daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Distributions or builds through Beta do not expire and there are no limits on the number of .IPAs or .APKs that can be uploaded to Beta.

Comment: Thanks :) for sharing this :)

Comment: A quick question :  If we upload a lot of .IPA’s then is it gonna charge us in anyway regarding space?

Comment: There is no charge for using Beta no matter how many uploads are sent our way :)